# Matlab: find specific variable from symbolic expression and/or system

Tags: variables, matlab, equation, symbolic-math

I have a system of three symbolic equations:

```
(1) Ua  = (Un*Ga -ia -(U2 -Ug2)*G3)/Ga;
(2) U2  = (Ug2*G3 -(Uc2m - Ua)*Ca*Fs)/(Ca*Fs + G3);
(3) Ug2 = ((Ua -Uc2m)*Ca*Fs* G3 -ig2*(Ca*Fs + G3)) / ((G3 + Gg2)*(Ca*Fs + G3) - G3*G3);
```

After substitutions of (3) inside (2) and (1), and then (2) inside (1), I have (1) as follows:

```
Ua  = (Un*Ga -ia -((((Ua -Uc2m)*Ca*Fs* G3 -ig2*(Ca*Fs + G3)) / ((G3 + Gg2)*(Ca*Fs + G3) - G3*G3)*G3 -(Uc2m - Ua)*Ca*Fs)/(Ca*Fs + G3) -((Ua -Uc2m)*Ca*Fs* G3 -ig2*(Ca*Fs + G3)) / ((G3 + Gg2)*(Ca*Fs + G3) - G3*G3))*G3)/Ga;
```

With `Ua` appearing both on the left and on the right member. Is there a way (with Matlab or any other tool) to:

1. Simplify the expression having only `Ua` on the left
2. Starting from the original system of three symbolic equations, simplify all of them automatically specifying what symbols consitute the three variables (that will appear on the left), and consider the rest as parameters to leave on the right.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did the substituions and got the long (1') expression, now I would like to simplify (1') so that there's no Ua,  on the right, but only the parameters.

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but have you checked `doc simplify`? And would you be able to get the result you like without matlab?

Comment: Thanks, simplify is very useful, but gives me another extended expression, similar to the one I have, of course more compact, but it's another f(Ua).What I'm looking for is a way to take an expression like "a*x + (b +c*x)/(d+e)" and get "x=f(a,b,c,d)". It could be done without matlab by manually solving the long but simple equation, but I will need to repeat the process many times with different and long expressions, so an automation would be useful and prevent eventual blackboard errors.

Comment: Could you show your code including the call to solve? Did you think about increasing the iterations and indicate for which variable the equation needs to be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure all of @RodyOldenhuis's hard work is required in this case. It's simply a matter of using `solve` correctly. When you provide N equations, it's usually best to ask for it to solve for N variables either of your choosing of its own (by not specifying any variable names):

```
syms Ua Ug2 U2 ia Un Ga G3 Uc2m Ca Fs ig2 Gg2
eqs = [Ua == (Un*Ga -ia -(U2 -Ug2)*G3)/Ga
       U2 == (Ug2*G3 -(Uc2m -Ua)*Ca*Fs)/(Ca*Fs + G3)
       Ug2 == ((Ua -Uc2m)*Ca*Fs*G3 -ig2*(Ca*Fs + G3)) / ((G3 + Gg2)*(Ca*Fs + G3) -G3*G3)];

s = solve(eqs,Ua,U2,Ug2)
```

Then `s.Ua` returns

```
-(G3*Gg2*ia - G3*Ga*Gg2*Un + Ca*Fs*G3*ia + Ca*Fs*G3*ig2 + Ca*Fs*Gg2*ia - Ca*Fs*G3*Gg2*Uc2m - Ca*Fs*G3*Ga*Un - Ca*Fs*Ga*Gg2*Un)/(G3*Ga*Gg2 + Ca*Fs*G3*Ga + Ca*Fs*G3*Gg2 + Ca*Fs*Ga*Gg2)
```

Don't make the mistake of passing in `Ua`, `U2`, and `Ug2` into `solve` as a vector (unless you're using R2015a+, I believe).

This works using the old string-based technique as well (the cell array could be replace by individual strings inputs if desired):

```
eqs = {'Ua = (Un*Ga -ia -(U2 -Ug2)*G3)/Ga'
       'U2 = (Ug2*G3 -(Uc2m -Ua)*Ca*Fs)/(Ca*Fs + G3)'
       'Ug2 = ((Ua -Uc2m)*Ca*Fs*G3 -ig2*(Ca*Fs + G3)) / ((G3 + Gg2)*(Ca*Fs + G3) -G3*G3)'};

s = solve(eqs{:},'Ua','U2','Ug2')
```

This works in R2013a and R2015a. I don't know if older versions can handle this or not.

Comment: You're right, I tested both your solutions on R2012a and they work fine without any scripting. Thanks!

Comment: @Freakk: ...I thought you wanted automated variable extraction, so that you only need to specify the variable you're interested in (`Ua` in this case). On second reading, I don't know why I thought that :)

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively I'd say just do `solve(expr1, expr2, expr3, 'Ua')`, but that doesn't seem to work, (at least on R2010a)...

So I got hacking. Now, I'm not much of a symbolic toolbox guy, so there's quite likely a "better" way to do this. Nevertheless, the following function answers both your questions:

```
function solution = solveFor(exprs, var)

    %// Split the equations up into the RHS and LHS
    C = regexp(expr, '\s*=\s*', 'split');
    C = cat(1, C{:});

    %// The equation we're solving for 
    kk = find(strcmp(C(:,1), var));

    %// Substitute every expression into every other expression
    for ii = 1:size(C,1)
        if ii==kk, continue; end

        for jj = 1:size(C,1)
            if jj==ii, continue; end

            C{jj,2} = regexprep(C{jj,2}, C{ii,1}, C{ii,2});
        end
    end

    %// Solve for the requested variable & simplify
    solution = simplify(solve([C{kk,1} '=' C{kk,2}], C{kk,1}));

end
```

Use like this:

```
>> expr{1} = 'Ua  = (Un*Ga -ia -(U2 -Ug2)*G3)/Ga';
>> expr{2} = 'U2  = (Ug2*G3 -(Uc2m - Ua)*Ca*Fs)/(Ca*Fs + G3)';
>> expr{3} = 'Ug2 = ((Ua -Uc2m)*Ca*Fs*G3 - ig2*(Ca*Fs + G3)) / ((G3 + Gg2)*(Ca*Fs + G3) - G3*G3)'; 
>> Ua = solveFor(expr, 'Ua')
Ua = 
    -(G3*Gg2*ia - G3*Ga*Gg2*Un + Ca*Fs*G3*ia + Ca*Fs*G3*ig2 + Ca*Fs*Gg2*ia - Ca*Fs*G3*Gg2*Uc2m - Ca*Fs*G3*Ga*Un - Ca*Fs*Ga*Gg2*Un)/(G3*Ga*Gg2 + Ca*Fs*G3*Ga + Ca*Fs*G3*Gg2 + Ca*Fs*Ga*Gg2)
```

Obvious limitations:

- all equations must be in the form above, e.g., `'single variable = expression'`
- equations must be given as strings and thus cannot be the outcome of other smybolic operations (although using `expr = cellfun(@char, expr, 'UniformOutput', false);` at the top would cancel that restriction)

### ***EDIT***

The call to `solve` that works has the following syntax:

```
S = solve(expr{:}, 'Ua,U2,Ug2');
```

So, to automate the process, you can modify the function above to the following simpler form:

```
function solution = solveFor(exprs, var)

    %// Syms or strings?
    if ~iscellstr(exprs) && all(cellfun('isclass', exprs, 'sym'))
        exprs = cellfun(@char, expr, 'UniformOutput', false); 
    else
        error(...);
    end

    %// Split the equations up into the RHS and LHS
    C = regexp(expr, '\s*=\s*', 'split');
    C = cat(1, C{:});

    %// Solve for the requested variables
    vars = cellfun(@(x)[x ','], C(:,1), 'UniformOutput', false);
    vars = [vars{:}];
    solution = solve(expr{:}, vars(1:end-1));

    %// Extract desired solution
    solution = simplify(solution.(var));

end
```

Comment: That's great! It's exactly what I was loking for. The first implementation works great, while the second returns an error "Undefined function 'simplify' for input arguments of type 'struct'." Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2374511: Ah yes, my mistake. Corrected.

Comment: @horchler: well, at least not with the equations from this question and the call to `solve` shown at the top of my answer. by the way, this also does not work on R2013a as I verified later. Specifying the 3 variables to solve for, and then selecting the right solution later on *does* work (the bit after my edit).